Why I am getting halos around some points that are plotted + Geom_Point +ggplot
I am generating boxplot overlayed with geom_points.For some of the geom_points, I see kind of halo/background around the point (See under the red and blue boxplots). What am I doing wrong and how can I remove this?
Here is the data:
Control <- structure(list(Genotype = c("DMCeibo", "DMCeibo", "DMCeibo", 
"DMCeibo", "DMCeibo", "DMCeibo", "MSINTA415", "MSINTA415", "MSINTA415", 
"MSINTA415", "MSINTA415", "MSINTA415", "Saeta", "Saeta", "Saeta", 
"Saeta", "Saeta", "Saeta"), Treatment = c("Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"), Year = c("2018(Wet)", 
"2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", 
"2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", 
"2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)", 
"2018(Wet)", "2018(Wet)"), Replication = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), GrainYield = c(4674, 
5250, 5387, 5144, 5276, 5397, 5244, 5411, 5436, 5679, 4704, 4810, 
5315, 4309, 5477, 5239, 4916, 5861), IndividualGrainWeight = c(46.3, 
46.8, 45.3, 46.3, 43.8, 45.7, 44.5, 44.5, 45, 44.5, 43, 44.3, 
42, 41, 40.5, 41, 42.5, 43), GrainNumber = c(10095, 11218, 11892, 
11110, 12046, 11810, 11784, 12160, 12080, 12762, 10940, 10858, 
12654, 10510, 13523, 12778, 11567, 13630), Protein = c(13.2, 
12.8, 12.6, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 15.2, 15, 14.8, 14.9, 15, 15.2, 
14.6, 14, 14.3, 14.9, 14.9, 14.4)), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 9L, 
13L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 29L, 33L, 37L, 41L, 45L, 49L, 53L, 57L, 61L, 
65L, 69L), class = "data.frame")

Code of generating the plot:
ggplot(
  Control,
  aes(
    x = Treatment,
    y = GrainYield,
    fill = Genotype,
    color = Genotype
  )
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Genotype),
    alpha = 0.2, lwd = 0.1, fatten = 1, position = position_dodge(0.8)
  ) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(transform = ~ . * 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Grain Yield (kg/ha)")


These halos are the outliers plotted by geom_boxplot by default. When adding the data points using geom_point you "duplicate" the outliers. To prevent the outliers from being plotted you can use geom_boxplot(..., outliers = FALSE) (requires ggplot2 >= 3.5.0) or geom_boxplot(..., outlier.shape = NA).

This is what it looks like on my end (R4.3.3; Ubuntu). I increased the size in geom_point(). Don't see any issues.

Please add to your question:

version of R? (add output of R.version)
operating System
are you using RStudio or something else?


The problem is that you have a few points being plotted twice. To change that you can turn off outlier plotting in geom_boxplot, see example:
ggplot(
  Control,
  aes(
    x = Treatment,
    y = GrainYield,
    fill = Genotype,
    color = Genotype
  )
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Genotype),
               alpha = 0.2, lwd = 0.1, fatten = 1, position = position_dodge(0.8),
outlier.shape = NA # this is the new line that will turn off the "halo" which is a low-alpha point behind the one you write in geom_point
  ) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(transform = ~ . * 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Grain Yield (kg/ha)")

